# How to get GC Information in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, garbage-collection

Silverlight does not provide perfmon counters for GC. How do i get GC Information?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight does not provide this information out of the box. You would have to use ETW tracing to get this information. Here is how you can get ETW information on [GC](http://naveensrinivasan.com/2010/03/21/get-gc-information-in-silverlight-using-etw/) from silverlight

Comment: By all means link to your own site, but quoting the relevant information here is seen as good practice.